# Can IMKCandidates `setCandidateData:` be used in place of IMKInputController `candidates:` delegate method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, input-method-kit

I'm creating an IMKCandidate candidate window for my Input Method Kit input method:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/IMKCandidates_Class/

> You then need to override the IMKInputController methods candidateSelectionChanged: and candidateSelected: as well as implement a candidates method in your delegate object. The IMKInputController subclass supplies candidates to the IMKCandidates object by implementing the candidates method. When you are ready to display a candidates window, call the candidates method to update candidates and to show the candidates window.

I've implemented the IMKInputController `candidates:` method to supply the array of candidates. This works great.

```
- (NSArray *)candidates:(id)sender {
    return @[@"`candidates:` method", @"This works great!"];
}
```

[image: <code>candidates:</code> method]

But I notice that a `setCandidateData:` method was added to set the candidate strings, as an alternative to relying on the delegate method. This would be more convenient in my input method.

> @abstract Set the candidates data directly rather than supplying data via `[IMKInputContoller candidates:]`.
>
> `-(void)setCandidateData:(NSArray*)candidatesArray AVAILABLE_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_7_AND_LATER;`

So I comment out the `candidates:` method, and use `setCandidateData:` instead:

```
[candidates setCandidateData:@[@"`setCandidateData:` method", @"Doesn't work :("]];
[candidates show:kIMKLocateCandidatesBelowHint];
```

However, when doing it this way no candidate window is shown:

[image]

I also see this error via the Console:

> CandidateWindowNoCandidatesException : IMKCandidates show: could not get candidate strings.

The docs seem pretty clear that `setCandidateData:` can be used in place of `candidates:`. Why then are the candidates not displayed?

Comment: Possibly no longer occurring in latest OS X: > I tried to use setCandidateData at HighSierra, and it works fine. So, its problem might not happen currently. https://twitter.com/mzp/status/918263309605920769